# Python: AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen'

Tags: python, pygame

I have problem with  AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen'. Please help me, code below:

```
class Settings():
def __init__(self):
    self.screen_width=1200
    self.screen_height=800
    self.bg_color=(230,230,230)

import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings=Settings()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen.height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Inwazja obcych")
    while True:
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.quit:
                sys.exit()
    pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

Comment: As @Ali Yilmaz mentions, it's a typo in line `screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen.height))`, where it should be `screen_height` instead of `screen.height`.

Answer (score 4):

it should've been `screen_height` with an underscore. your code has `screen.height` instead